# Out of curiosity -- why don't logging APIs implement printf()-like logging methods?

Tags: java, logging

Whether it be java.util.logging, commons-logging, log4j, and even the most recent slf4j and logback, none of these APIs propose methods such as, say:

```
void debug(String format, Object... args);
```

where `format` is a string parsed using `Formatter`. Instead, they stick with `MessageFormat`.

I understand that it would conflict with existing prototypes, so why not `debugf()` or the like, but why aren't there any such methods given that `Formatter` is as old as Java 1.5?

Is it for performance reasons, backwards compatibility... ?

(note, I am *really* talking about `Formatter`, ie including placeholders such as `%s`, `%02x` etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

slf4j does. See http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html. It's one of the main advantages (to me) of slf4j over log4j. It avoids the need for `isDebugEnabled()` everywhere.

EDIT :

The [slf4j documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance) explains why it doesn't use the standard formatting from the JDK:

> SLF4J uses its own message formatting implementation which differs
>   from that of the Java platform. This is justified by the fact that
>   SLF4J's implementation performs about 10 times faster but at the cost
>   of being non-standard and less flexible.

Comment: Well, not that I can see: it uses `{}` for placeholders, not, say, `%s` or `%d` or anything similar

Comment: Lots of people hate %s due to i18n considerations, and believe that java message formatting like {0} et al. is superior.

Comment: OK. I thought you were just asking about using formats (in general), and not specifically Formatter formats.

Comment: @bmargulies GNU has solved this for a long time with gettext, though

Comment: Huh? Java solved it with {0}. Admittedly, some fancy printf's mix in selector number tool.

Comment: @bmargulies I was referring to your i18n comment. Bah, nevermind