# LogBack use MessageFormat

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback, messageformat

Is it possible to use MessageFormat in logback ?

I saw that it uses slf4j MessageFormat**ter**, because its faster as said here:
[Out of curiosity -- why don't logging APIs implement printf()-like logging methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635769/out-of-curiosity-why-dont-logging-apis-implement-printf-like-logging-metho)

> SLF4J uses its own message formatting implementation which differs
>   from that of the Java platform. This is justified by the fact that
>   SLF4J's implementation performs about 10 times faster but at the cost
>   of being non-standard and less flexible.

[From sf4j Documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance)

The ideia is to use the full stack feature of MessageFormat like that:

```
 Object[] arguments = {
     new Integer(7),
     new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
     "a disturbance in the Force"
 };

 String result = MessageFormat.format(
     "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.",
     arguments);

 output: At 12:30 PM on Jul 3, 2053, there was a disturbance
           in the Force on planet 7.
```

anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question... basically it's a performance issue.  If the slf4j implementations were forced to find and parse the parameterizations... well.. overhead that nobody seems to want to have in a logging system.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j 2 supports the slf4j format, MessageFormat and String.format syntaxes, as well as supporting a set of printf methods.